# wander removal to get accurate baseline using octave/python

Tags: python, octave, baseline

I have a set of files with raw data(set of points) which when plotted looks something like this.

[image]

I want to correct baseline and make it something like this. (not exactly same, but the baseline should be horiozontal)
[image]

How can this be done using octave/python?

Comment: Apply a high-pass filter to remove the "0Hz frequency" so in octave something like `conv(signal, [-1 -1 -1 7 -1 -1 -1])`, otherwise do a linear regression and then subtract the regression line

Comment: See detrend in GNU Octave to fit a polynomial and substract it